# Passing more kwargs into a function than initially set

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Is there a way to send more kwargs into a function than is called for in the function call?

Example:

```
def mydef(a, b):
    print a
    print b

mydict = {'a' : 'foo', 'b' : 'bar'}
mydef(**mydict)    # This works and prints 'foo' and 'bar'

mybigdict = {'a' : 'foo', 'b' : 'bar', 'c' : 'nooooo!'}
mydef(**mybigdict)   # This blows up with a unexpected argument error
```

Is there any way to pass in `mybigdict` without the error?  `'c'` would never be used in `mydef` in my ideal world and would just be ignored.

Thanks, my digging has not come up with what I am looking for.

Edit: Fixed the code a bit.  The `mydef(a, b, **kwargs)` was the form that I was looking for, but the inspect function args was a new thing to me and definitely something for my toolbox.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: The code you present is invalid, the first call blows up too. I think you want to remove the 2s in the keys.

Comment: Note that while you can do `mydict = { 'a':'foo', 'b':'bar' }` and pass that to `mydef(**dict)`.  Using dicts and (non)keyword arguments this way is not common.  You'll sometimes see if it you defined mydef with default arguments : `mydef(a=None, b=None)`, but rarely will you see it passed that way with regular arguments ...  With regular arguments, you'll more frequently see: `mytuple = ('foo','bar')` and then the call uses the (single) splat operator:  `mydef(*mytuple)`

Comment: @mgilson: using a keyword syntax for positional arguments is perfectly legal and useful at times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I didn't say it was illegal (I said that it isn't common).  Even accessing positional arguments by keyword I can see (a little bit).  However, unpacking a dictionary for positional arguments I can't see a use for.  It's simply unclear what the function is receiving (in my opinion) -- Would you do this with `dict`s instead of `tuples`?  I haven't come across a case where I would ...

Comment: @mgilson: it simplifies code where you have both keyword and positional arguments, for one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Maybe I'm wrong (because I don't use this idiom and haven't seen it used ...), but it seems to me like it would obfuscate that code to simply save a line or two.  I suppose maybe if you support this sort of thing, I should give it a try for a while and see if I confuse myself too much (retracting my former statement if necessary).

Comment: @mgilson My code is still very flexible at this point.  Would using a tuple be more kosher?  I was only using a dict because it was what I was familiar with.  If I use the tuple what would I use rather than **kwargs to pass in the additional unused variables?  Also, if I pass in a tuple the order would become important.  Correct?

Comment: @deadstump -- In my workflow, I pass `tuples` to positional arguments, and I pass `dicts` to default and keyword arguments.  So, a typical function call of mine might look like:  `myfunc(*mytuple,**mydict)` where `func` is defined: `def func(a,b,c=2,**kwargs):` and `mytuple` might be `(1, 2)`.  Apparently some people might do it differently (as you have been doing it) and MartijnPieters corroborates.  You're right that with tuples, the order matters and the order is the order that you would pass the arguments to the positional arguments in the underlying function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To clarify Martijn Pieters's answer (for sake of clarity). It's possible if you change the function signature to:

`def mydef(a, b, **kwargs):`

This means it's not possible without changing the signature. But if that's not a problem it'll work.

Answer (score 21):

No, unless the function definition allows for more parameters (using the `**kwargs` catch-all syntax), you cannot call a method with more arguments than it has defined.

You *can* introspect the function and remove any arguments it won't accept however:

```
import inspect

mybigdict = {'a2' : 'foo', 'b2' : 'bar', 'c2' : 'nooooo!'}
sig = inspect.signature(mydef)
if not any(p.kind == p.VAR_KEYWORD for p in sig.parameters.values()):
    for missing in mybigdict.keys() - sig.parameters.keys():
        del mybigdict[missing]
mydef(**mybigdict)
```

I'm using the [`inspect.signature()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) to check if the callable supports a `**kwarg` catch-all (by looking for a `Parameter.VAR_KEYWORD` entry), and if it doesn't, I use the set difference between `mybigdict` and the signature `.parameters` mapping to remove anything the method won't support.

Comment: I was considering suggesting to add some `**kwargs` in the definition of `mydef`, but I think you'll agree it's a false good idea: there's no way to ensure the order of the arguments...

Comment: The `inspect` method will modify your `mybigdict`, though, which may have some undesirable side-effects.

Comment: @PierreGM: It's easy enough to make a copy, isn't it? I'm trying to illustrate a technique in a reasonably concise manner, not cover all eventualities here.