# Inject **kwargs into a function in order to avoid TypeError

Tags: python

I'm working with this module that has a function without `**kwargs` in the signature, thus if I pass a parameter that is not there I receive a `TypeError`. I would like to call this function by unpacking a dict in a way that the parameters not present in the signature are just ignored (let's assume that since it's an external module I cannot change the signature).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093751/6768966) that suggests using the `inspect` module to remove all the arguments that are not present in the signature ,from the dict being passed. Is this still the only way to do this or has something changed in the latest Python versions?

Comment: Is it possible to just add an attribute to the object, like `a = SomeClass(); a.my_dict = d`? Why do you want to change their `__init__`?

Comment: @Tobias I'm not trying to change the `__init__`. I have this function that is defined like `def foo(a1=None, ..., an=None)` (notice the missing of `**args`) and I would like to call it with the dict unpacking `foo(**mydict)` in a way that it ignores the parameters not present in the signature.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking you could use the fact that `kwargs` will be an `OrderedDict` according to [PEP-468](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/), but since you will not have all positional arguments it won't work. I was thinking you could do something like `zip(args, kwargs)`. So yeah, go with the `inspect` module.

Comment: I'd also look into using `func.__defaults__` since all your arguments have a default value.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks, but `__defaults__` returns only the values and I need the keys as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using the inspect module inside a decorator, since there doesn't seem to be another way around it. I'm on Python 3.6.2.

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def inject_kwargs(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(f)
        if not argspec.varkw:  # function does not accept arbitrary keywords arguments
            return f(*args, **{k: kwargs[k] for k in kwargs if k in argspec.args})
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@inject_kwargs
def test(foo=None, bar=None):
    print(foo, bar)

x = {'bar': 1, 'baz': 2}
test(**x)  # now prints (None, 1) without raising any error
```